# Read version from parent pom.xml and put in a .properties file

Tags: maven

I am working on a project which has multiple modules.and each module has its own pom.xml and its own base-config.properties
I want pick up the version from the parent pom.xml and put it into base-config.properties
I write in base-config.properties: version=${project.parent.version}
but it is undefined for it. I don't have this problem in a single module project but I don't know why it doesn't work here.
Can someone help me?

Comment: First what kind of information do you have in the `base-config.properties`? Do you have a multi module build?

Comment: I found the problem why it doesn't recognize it. It was because it hadn't added this to my pom:

Comment: <resources>
     <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
     </resource>
    </resources>

Comment: But I don't understand the reason